# How to highlight if else end in atom/sublime?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have a big page of code in ruby and it's really hard to found what 'end' corresponds to what 'if'.
Is there a way to do configure it in Atom or Sublime?

I want to be able to see the "end" of the "if" when I press on the "if" and opposite.

Comment: Did you try to set the language to "Ruby"? you can do that in the bottom-right corner in Sublime Text.

Comment: sublime - view -> syntax -> ruby, when I press on the "if" , all "ifs" are highlight in the file.

Comment: I see. Not sure how you can do this, but instead you can fold the if/else block to see where it ends.

Comment: You could try the Sublime Text package [BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter). It seems to support ruby.

Comment: The real issue is not that your editor currently does not highlight the `if`...`else` block but that the block is too big. Refactor the code: extract the logic inside the block to a separate method. Repeat until you have short methods, each of which fits on the screen and does one thing well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in Atom by installing the [Ruby Block](https://atom.io/packages/ruby-block) package.